# help with xsl if statement

Tags: xslt, search-results

I am trying to change the icon for the "Link to Document" on the searchResult.aspx page. I added following to the xslt of the result but then the result webpart never renders meaning the code is broke. I tried to follow SP2007 article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789805(v=office.12).aspx) but my environment is SP 2010. Please suggest.

```
<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test="contenttype='LegalLinkedDocument'"> 
<img align="absmiddle" src="_layouts/images/legalIcon.gif" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
 <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" /> </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use @ContentType as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the nodes. You never close out your `xsl:if` statement.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp

Just like XML, every tag needs a beginning and end.

I'm not sure exactly what you're doing here, but I think an `xsl:choose` statement might be more appropriate to handle the `else` portion of the `if...else` statement via `xsl:otherwise`.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_choose.asp

Comment: You are right the ending for if statement needed /. Now I dont get error but the icon's are not showing up.

Comment: Well, care to update your code? I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: I updated the code from IF to When so I can put Otherwise. The result webpart renders without any error but the desire icon for content type is not showing.

Comment: Sounds like your `test` statement isn't resulting in true. Are you sure `contenttype` is the property you need? The article talks about a `contentclass` value.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the contenttype value into a variable before using it in the condition

```
<xsl:variable name="contenttype" select="contenttype"/>
<xsl:choose>  
  <xsl:when test="$contenttype = 'LegalLinkedDocument'">  
    <img align="absmiddle" src="_layouts/images/legalIcon.gif" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" /> 
  </xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise> 
    <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
  </xsl:otherwise> 
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [link](http://www.prosharepointsearch.com/?p=240) and then compared:

```
<xsl:when test="ctype='LegalLinkedDocument'">
```

Now it's all good.

@Per Jakobsen: Your solution did not work for me.

Comment: I am unable to Mark this post as answer (Dont even see that option). Can someone please mark this post as an answer. Thanks